# Removing required password for sudo command to be executed in python

Tags: python, terminal

I have a terminal command I wish to execute from a python file.
However this command needs says it needs to be run as root (i.e sudo).
I am running this command from a python file by doing:

```
os.system(sudo pmset schedule wake  "08/31/21 00:26:00")
```

its basically just telling my laptop to wakeup at a specific time.

As you know that this then requires requires a the users password to be manually input to execute the command. Is there a way of removing this from requiring a password? i was trying to enter my password in as an 'os.system' command but it wont take. it seems like only a manual input will work. any ideas?

Comment: You do this by configuring `sudo` to allow the command to be run without a password. Not a programming question anyway.

Comment: I am not super familiar with Python, but that doesn't look like a line of Python to me.

Comment: I'm no linux expert, but I think you would have to write an elevated privileged daemon that can receive a message and issue that command you have there.   (Plus, please fix the quotations in your example.)

Answer (score -1):

If using subprocess, you have the option to run a command as shell, with the `shell=True` argument. However, this requires the python program to already be running with elevated privilages (run python with sudo), otherwise it is not permitted to start a subprocess with an elevated privilage.

You can read more about the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run